# Get html string from jquery dynamically created object

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm populating a jQuery datatable dynamically. For instance columnData.push(10) works as expected. However, I need to create a dynamic text box and push it columnData array. Is there a way to convert below jquery object to string?

```
$('<input/>').attr({ type: 'text', id: 'test', name: 'test', autofocus: 'true',value:flavorCount }
```

Comment: to string in the sense? you want it as a html String?

Comment: just do : $("#test")[0].outerHTML after creating the element dynamically if you wish to get the html string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("<input/>", {
    "type": 'text', 
    "id": 'test', 
    "name": 'test', 
    "value": flavorCount 
}).prop("outerHTML");
```